# Active Admin use current user attribute in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, activeadmin

I wanna define a scope that shows me my own mission (Doesn't matter what is a mission in this context)

What i tried is:

```
scope :my_mission do |missions|
  missions.where("mission.id = #{user.mission_id}")
end
```

Where mission_id is an User model attribute. user is the active logged in. This code has to live into the ActiveAdmin.register Mission file. Any idea on how to retrieve the user to perform the Query?

Comment: Also tried: signed_in_user.mission_id but this seems to be blocking the resources on the server

Answer (score 1):

ActiveAdmin uses AdminUser model thus:

```
current_admin_user or current_active_admin_user == current_user
```

Your scope definition can be this way:

```
scope :my_mission do |missions|
  missions.where(admin_user_id == current_admin_user.id)
end
```

or in your case search for a single mission

```
scope :my_mission do |missions|
  Mission.find(current_admin_user.mission)
end
```

Comment: This isn't the same query that i have to perform...Now this is working with only current_user. Like that: 

scope :my_mission do |missions|
    missions.where("missions.id = #{current_user.mission_id}")
end

Comment: @halbano - what is your model relationship like? does AdminUser has mission? or only User model?

Comment: I build active_admin only with the User model. rails g active_admin:install --skip-users # skips user authentication entirely

Comment: @halbano - you should still be able to use current_admin_user

Comment: current_admin_user is nil. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

The active admin user is called

```
AdminUser
```

by default. The corresponding devise helper method is therefore

```
current_admin_user.
```

reference: [How to get the current user that is logged in via active admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470387/how-to-get-the-current-user-that-is-logged-in-via-active-admin)